# Do you have to be proficient in a weapon to use it?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, proficiency

Do you have to be proficient in martial weapons to use a martial weapon for example?

Comment: Related, probably cousins: [Do you have to be proficient in armour to use it?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87177/23970)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### No.

So, why care about using a weapon with which you're proficient?

> You add your proficiency bonus to your attack roll when you attack using a weapon with which you have proficiency.... (PHB p.194, "Attack Rolls")

See also pp.12 and 14 ("Building Bruenor") and p.146 ("Weapon Proficiency").

So you can certainly attack using a weapon with which you're not proficient: you're just rather less-likely to *hit* when you do than if you'd used a weapon with which you are proficient.