# Do you have to be proficient in armour to use it?

Tags: dnd-5e, armor, proficiency

Do you have to be proficient in armour to be able to actually wear it?

Comment: If the answer has resolved your problem/question, you can accept it, or wait for a better answer.  Welcome to RPG.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how the Q&A site works.  Thanks for the question and happy gaming.

Comment: Related, probably cousins: [Do you have to be proficient in a weapon to use it?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/87174)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**No, you don't.** However:

> If you wear armor that you lack proficiency with, you have
>   disadvantage on any ability check, saving throw, or attack roll that
>   involves Strength or Dexterity, and you can’t cast spells.

(Player's Handbook, page 144)

The rules are designed so that it's not a good idea to regularly wear armour you're not proficient with, but they give you the option for when you really need the AC more than you need your abilities, attacks, or spells.

Comment: So probably not a good idea to wear it anyway! Thank you!

Comment: If you're going into a situation where they won't have to make any of those checks, it can be worth it.  Basically if you're trying to avoid being killed by arrows while peeking over the top of the battlements to see how many troops are out there or something.